# problema al dar accion a un botpn

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando reconocer el sistema operativo desde el que se está ejecutando mi aplicacion, y en funcion de éste abrir un documento u otro. El error que me da es "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" pero ya la he definido en la linea de encima.

```
let botonSO = document.getElementsByClassName(".appButton");

        $(botonSO).onclick(function () {
            if (navigator.userAgent.match((iPhone | iPad))) {
                document.open("/apple/index.html")
                console.log("Ios")

            } else if (navigator.userAgent.match((Android))) {
                document.open("/android/index.html")
                console.log("android")
            } else {
                console.log("OS no supporteado")
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `getElementsByClassName()` devuelve una lista de nodos, no un elemento individual. Tampoco acepta la clase con el punto adelante. En su lugar tienes que emplear el método `querySelector()` el cual sí acepta el punto y devuelve un elemento individual.

Por otro lado, no veo necesidad de hacer esto: `$(botonSO)` si con `botonSO` puedes trabajar directamente. No sé si estás utilizando alguna librería como jQuery que es de las que usa el `$()`, pero por la manera en la que intentas obtener el elemento en la línea de arriba, creo que no es el caso. De igual forma, el `onclick()` que utilizas no funcionará de esa manera. En su lugar necesitas echar mano del método `addEventListener()` para registrar el evento:

```
botonSO.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //...
}, false);
```